# Unable to install PyAudio even after installing wheel from Chris Gohlke

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I was trying to make a simple speech recognition assistant when I stumbled upon this error.

```
'''Could not import the PyAudio C module '_portaudio'.
import _portaudio as pa
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "C:\Users\John\anaconda3\envs\Python 36\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
  File "C:\Users\John\anaconda3\envs\Python 36\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio
    raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation'''
```

I have previously faced the error of improper installation of PyAudio, and I have successfully fixed it a couple of times previously by installing the respective PyAudio wheel from
[1]: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)
Chris Gohlke's Unofficial Windows Binaries.

However, this time, I am not able to do so.
I have installed it by downloading the wheel and it shows successfully installed PyAudio but shows the above given error when I run the code. Here's the code:

```
def receiveCommand():

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        r.energy_threshold = 350
        audio = r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio = r.listen(source, timeout=1, phrase_time_limit=5)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"User said: {query}\n")
        return query

    except Exception as e:
        print("Say that again, please")
        speak("Could you please say that again " + USER + "?")
        return "None"
    query = query.lower()
    return query
```

I am using Python 3.6 on Anaconda. (Windows 10)

Comment: are you using the same environment where you are downloading that wheel file and installing and activating same environment to run above code??

Comment: @BhavyaParikh Yes I am using the same environment.

Comment: activate your environment show image what output you are getting after using this command `pip show pyaudio` and also mention  full error traceback from running above code

Comment: @BhavyaParikh, thanks for your time and concern. I somehow managed to fix it by creating a whole new environment and reinstalling everything... Don't know what could have caused the issue, though. Anyways, thanks